# For loop passes list with step: 2, but i didn`t want it

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i in a:
  print(i) # returns 1,3,5
  if i < 5:
    a.remove(i)
print(a) # returns [2,4,5]
```

Just for example. This code is used in codewars solution.

Comment: `a.remove(i-1)` ?

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: Expected output is print(i) - 1,2,3,4,5 and print(a) - [5]

Comment: a.remove(i-1) = ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Comment: If you change your for loop iterator, it will work as expected. So `for i in range(1, 5)` (or `for i in range(1, len(a))` if you need to reference `a`) instead of `for i in a` - it's because you are changing the list while iterating through it.

Comment: statnet22, thank you.

Comment: I'll pop it in as an answer, so you can mark the issue as solved :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you change your for loop iterator, it will work as expected. So for `i in range(1, 5)` (or `for i in range(1, len(a))` if you need to reference `a`) instead of `for i in a` - it's because you are changing the list while iterating through it.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i in a:
  print(i) # returns 1,3,5
  if i < 5:
    a.remove(i)
print(a) # returns [2,4,5]
```

The issue here is for loop is going through index.

```
   Iteration 1:a=[1,2,3,4,5]
    index =0
    i=1
    while you are doing a.remove will remove 1 and list will have [2,3,4,5]
    
    Iteration 2:a=[2,3,4,5]
    index=1
    i=3
    2 will be skipped as it is in index 0 now.
```

which is giving the result such a way